# Why is there a 10 second delay in this http conversation?

Tags: html, http, tcp, webserver, wireshark

I've got a weird situation. The first time I hit an embedded web server (uclinux/boa) at 10.1.10.29, I get a 10 second delay in the browser window before things start happening.  "first time" means I haven't hit the machine in a few days.  Browser type/OS doesn't matter (source is 10.1.10.20)

I've got a wireshark capture of it happening.

[image: a bunch of frames]

And here is the detail of frame 296:
[image: frame detail 296]

Note packet 374 doesn't pop out for around 10 seconds after 296.  The packets between those 2 aren't from the machine in question.  It's just sitting there for 10 seconds and decides to retransmit.  How's it supposed to work?

Comment: I have no idea if this is related, but I've noticed that on packet `374`, the window size decreases to `9056`. I've also noticed that TCP Window Scaling is in use. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) suggests that this can cause a user's Internet connection to malfunction intermittently for a few minutes, then appear to start working again for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add the answer that solved our problem that had the problem with the 10 second delay, then working and after 5 minutes of inactivity adding another 10 seconds delay.

First of all, we wiresharked everything, and tried to find some kind of error in code, or in the way that the computer or server handled the network traffic. Found nothing out of the ordinary.

After much searching we found it was a DNS-"problem". In the DNS-server that the client computer used, there were dual entries for the domain name of the server. One was correct and one (the first one in the list) was wrong.

So removing the wrong dns pointer solved the problem.

This means the problem was that the computer tried the first address it got, waited 10seconds to get a reply, didnt get it and went to the second address in line. This creates no error messages as this is how DNS is supposed to work. And that is why all our wireshark logs showed up as just waiting 10 seconds with no error and no reason, and then just jump into life, work for as long as the DNS record is valid (5 minutes in our case) and then the procedure needs to be done again.

Hope this helps someone who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is most certainly because the code was swapped out from memory.

MS-Windows is really bad in that regard. If some program does not get used for "too long", it gets swapped out of memory. Period. When you come back at it, it has to re-read it back from the hard drive.

The one good thing (main reason) Windows does that is to defragment the kernel memory. For that, it is good.

You have similar problems under Linux, however, only if your server needs the memory. In other words, if you have tons of processes and they all fight for as much of memory as possible, then it is likely to swap out the least used software. Otherwise it will stay in place.

If you were to use the Cassandra database system, you would notice that on any computer that runs anything else than Cassandra. If you just run Cassandra, it remains fast all the time. If you run other software that use a lot of the memory, Cassandra is slow on first access. This is particularly noticeable.

Comment: But, the delay in the wireshark doesn't take place due to the gathering of data from memory.  The data has already been transferred.

Comment: Hmmm... there could be a collision problem on your network. I have had problems like that a long time ago where some LAN would not respond right. But usually that does not go away after a first hit.

Comment: It's like clockwork for multiple devices.  If I haven't hit it in a while, it will ALWAYS have a delay right at that spot.  I'm thinking it's not a delay, but something else haywire with the ACK/FIN stuff (because of the retransmission stuff.)

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or a random rant on Windows' memory management, based on nothing but a guess? Unless you literally have a rusty harddisk for your swap and the memory demands greatly outrun the supply, tough luck getting a process to not respond at all for ten seconds due to swapping.

Comment: It seems likely the web server itself is memory at that time, since it does respond with the status line and headers. It may be that whatever the resource involves could be swapped out to disk (though 10 seconds is a long time for that). It could also be a stateful firewall issue of some sort -- if it's consistently about 10 seconds, that may indicate it's some kind of policy enforcement.